# how to read correctly both date and time in the same column from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have both date and time in same column of a csv data file but my python code is only reading date and not time

```
date = []
val = []
with open('F:/India 4 hrs 15-16.csv', 'r') as data:
csvreader = csv.reader(data)
for i in range(0,17):
    next(csvreader)
for row in csvreader:
    date.append(row[1])
    val.append(row[3])

#for conversion into desired format


 for k in range(0, len(val)):
   if (val[k]== 'None') :
    val[k]= 0
   else : 
    val[k]= float(val[k])


  for j in range(0,len(date)):
  dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M').date() for d in 
  date]

  print(dates)
```

it gives the output only date and not time , where is the error ? 
the data is given as : 
[below is the link to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSZn4.png)

Comment: Could you please add a minimum version of that csv file also?

Comment: Put your question in body, not in title

Comment: Also put the sample csv in the question, not in comments

Comment: @friend if you remove the `.date()` after `strptime`, it should have both date and time. Did you try it?

Comment: yeah it worked @mfrackowiak ty :)

Comment: can anyone say how to increase the spacing between the adjacent points in the plot ? since in the above there are many nearby so its getting congested.